# Errors sending emails via mailgun

Tags: email, dns, mailgun

A few of the emails being sent from my account are getting rejected. These are the error messages:

1. Server response: 550 550 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable invalid DNS MX or A/AAAA resource record
2. From: Domain is invalid. Please provide a valid From: IB506 http://x.co/srbounce

Is this issue on my end or their (the receivers) end? How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely set up an MX record for your domain but not the subdomain from which the email is being sent. You need to set up an MX record for the subdomain also.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the following MX records to your DNS and associate them with the subdomain `mg.yourdomain.com`

```
mxa.mailgun.org  10
mxb.mailgun.org  10
```

Likely you are seeing those errors because certain email servers do an MX lookup on the domain of the sender of the email (in this case mg.yourdomain.com). If those MX records do not exist, the server will reject the mail.

Comment: Perfect, exactly was the issue.  Strange, because google doesn't reject due to this reason which is why it threw me for a loop.

Comment: Yea, I had the exact same problem and confusion :-)